# Can't put icons into the search bar

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I've only been doing HTML and CSS for a total of one month. I'm currently trying to replicate a Google search bar, but the problem is that I can't seem to fit the search icon and the voice icon inside the search bar. I've read that you're supposed to put the search bar's position as relative and the icons' as absolute, but I've apparently screwed up the code somewhere and can't figure it out. Thank you <3

My code **(HTML and CSS)**:

```css
input {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    width: 600px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    outline-color: none;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
}

.voice {
    height:20px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;  
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.search-icon {
    color: rgb(154, 160, 166);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="search-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" />
    <input class="search" type="text">
    <a href="#"> <img class="voice" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png" title="Search by Voice"></a>
  </div>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is that it's not the text field that has the rounded corners and shadows, with the icons on top, but it's the wrapper that needs to have the rounded corners and borders and every, then the three elements all go inside of it.

so what I did is that I took your styles for the input, and moved it too the wrapper, then make the `border:none`, so the input is basically invisible.

then I removed all of your position styles because they aren't needed, so now we are basically done, except the elements are slightly off center, and the input doesn't fill the whole width.

I just decided to use `display:flex` on the wrapper, with `flex-direction:row` to make all of it horizontal, with `align-items: center` to center everything. I also added `flex-grow:1` to the input so it fills the entire width.

```css
input {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    outline-color: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    height:100%;
    flex-grow:1;
    font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.voice {
    height:20px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

.search-icon {
    color: rgb(154, 160, 166);
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    outline-color: none;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: transparent;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper:hover{
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="search-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" />
        <input class="search" type="text">
        <a href="#"> <img class="voice" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png" title="Search by Voice"></a>
      </div>  
    </form>
```

I also changed some padding and stuff slightly to make it work better but I guess that's optional

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
        width: 600px;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        outline-color: none;
        cursor: text;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    input:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    
    input:hover {
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
    }
    
    .voice {
        height:20px;
        top: 10;
        right: 40;  
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    
    .search-icon {
        color: rgb(154, 160, 166);
        position: absolute;
        right:20;
        top:10;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
        width:600px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
  <form id="search-form">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <img class="search-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" />
            <input class="search" type="text">
            <a href="#"> <img class="voice" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png" title="Search by Voice"></a>
          </div>  
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
   font-size:20px;
   width: 88%;
   border:none;
   margin-left:60px;
   height:30px;
   padding:0;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
}

.voice {
    height:20px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;  
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.search-icon {
    color: rgb(154, 160, 166);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 15px;  
    top: 10px;
    cursor:default;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    width: 600px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    outline-color: none;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: transparent;
   
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="search-icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" />
        <input class="search" type="text">
        <a href="#"> <img class="voice" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Google_mic.svg/716px-Google_mic.svg.png" title="Search by Voice"></a>
      </div>  
    </form>
```